# How I summed all the values in a particular column up to the current line

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with binary column (`my_column`) and an `id` columns.
I want to create a new column that for each row sums all the values in the binary column  which belong to the same id up to his row but does not include the row itself.

Sample Input:

```
    id  my_column
0   111 0
1   111 1
2   111 1
3   111 0
4   222 1
5   222 1
6   222 1
7   222 1
```

Sample output:

```
    id  my_column   new_column
0   111 0           0
1   111 1           0
2   111 1           1
3   111 0           2
4   222 1           0
5   222 1           1
6   222 1           2
7   222 1           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops (non-vectorized code which should be slower as compared to more elegant answer by @stef)

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {
    'id':[111,111,111,111,222,222,222,222, 111],
      'my_column':[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)        
print (df)

new_column = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  adf = df[:i]
  adf = adf[adf['id'] == df.iloc[i]['id']]  
  if len(adf) > 0:
    new_column.append(sum(adf['my_column']))    
  else:
    new_column.append(0)

df['new_column'] = new_column
print (df)
```

**Output**:

```
    id  my_column
0  111          0
1  111          1
2  111          1
3  111          0
4  222          1
5  222          1
6  222          1
7  222          1
8  111          1

    id  my_column  new_column
0  111          0           0
1  111          1           0
2  111          1           1
3  111          0           2
4  222          1           0
5  222          1           1
6  222          1           2
7  222          1           3
8  111          1           2
```

Comment: if loop, I suggest use numba ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `cumsum`:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('id').my_column.transform('cumsum') - df.my_column
```

This will sum all rows over the same id (excluding the current one). If you want the sum over consecutive id blocks and start over with 0 if id blocks repeat, then you can use the following:

```
df['new_column_1'] = df.groupby(df.id.ne(df.id.shift()).cumsum()).my_column.transform('cumsum') - df.my_column
```

See the different behaviour for the last row in the following example:

```
    id  my_column  new_column  new_column_1
0  111          0           0             0
1  111          1           0             0
2  111          1           1             1
3  111          0           2             2
4  222          1           0             0
5  222          1           1             1
6  222          1           2             2
7  222          1           3             3
8  111          1           2             0
```

Comment: I think OP wants `sums all the values in the binary column which belong to the same id up to his row`

Comment: @mujjiga so you mean if id 111 comes again after 222 the sum should start over with 0?

Comment: Yes that's what I think OP wants, but I will wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: @mujjiga: Yes, let's wait for clarification. If the sum should start over it would be `df['new_column'] = df.groupby(df.id.ne(df.id.shift()).cumsum()).my_column.transform('cumsum') - df.my_column`

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the answer. appreciate it a lot!
Yes the sum needs to start over.
And it seems to me that it works

Comment: @טלאהרון: I've updated the answer to illustrate both approaches. If this solves your problem you should consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This helps to keep this site useful to quickly find solutions to similar questions. Thanks.